# `jobs` command doesn't show any background processes

Tags: linux, bash

When I was in the office using my desktop, I started a script `run.sh` in background 4 times.

```
run.sh parameter1 &
run.sh parameter2 &
run.sh parameter3 &
run.sh parameter4 &
```

Then I came home, and opened a terminal on my laptop, ssh to the desktop in my office. When ran `ps -u jack`, I saw the started processes:

```
 3562 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 4540 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4643 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 4748 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
```

But when I typed `jobs`, I got nothing. Why I could see these four running background processes?

Btw, how can I bring them back to my current terminal, so that I can kill one of them, say `run.sh parameter4 &`?

Comment: Where did you started the script, in a remote machine?

Comment: @fedorqui No the script was started on my desktop directly.

Comment: Did you run `jobs` command in the same shell?

Comment: @Grzegorz No, I opened a new one from my laptop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the problem statement of the question, IMHO I do not see any reason for using `background` or `foreground`. All you care is to find a process which is running in background so that you can kill it.

Run `ps -ef | grep parameter3` to find processes which has `parameter3` in the process name. You can adapt the `grep` to uniquely identify a process, given you don't have two processes with exactly same process name.

Once you have it, just do `kill -9 PID` and that process will be killed.  So no need for bringing that process to the foreground for killing it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw this `jack    15766  3562  0 Jun12 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./run.sh 015d4a826e43f416` which number is the pid?

Comment: @JackVW the second column is the PID. So you will do `kill -9 15766`. If you care, the third column is PPID (PID of the parent process).

Comment: Why `kill -9`? It's almost always better to start by using kill without the signal parameter first. That way, the killed process can tidy up before terminating if it has been programmed that way. Then if the process still refuses to die, you can use kill -9.

Answer (score 22):

This is because `jobs` shows background commands started from (belonging to) the same shell. The shell processes running under your desktop terminal and under ssh terminal are different.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html

To be able to control your processes as jobs from different terminals you can use `screen` or `tmux` which are basically virtual terminal managers and can re-connect them to any number of other terminals.

For example, with `screen` you just start it, it opens your default shell and you work with it as you would with any other shell. Then when you get home and ssh to your office machine, you can run `screen -d -r` to detach the virtual terminal from your office desktop terminal and attach it to your ssh terminal, resuming the work. You can detach the virtual terminal from within `screen` itself by pressing Ctrl-A, d.

Comment: Thanks for the info, then how can I bring them back to my current terminal?

Comment: If you wish to run things "in the background", so to speak, and resume them later then something like GNU Screen or tmux would be useful. This will allow your to resume from any subsequent shell sessions whereas, as described above, you can only bring background jobs to the foreground from the same shell.

Comment: @JackWM use `fg`

Comment: @Bill Does `fg` require a background process number, which I don't have?

Comment: You can only foreground jobs in the shell which spawned them. A job is distinct from a process; the former is a shell concept that might encompass several processes, while the latter is a system concept whose only connection to the spawning shell is the parent/child relationship.

Comment: @JackWM yes, `fg` uses jobId, sorry this will not help u :(

Comment: @JackWM just curious....if you want to bring the processes to foreground just to kill them, cann't you use `kill -9 PID`? `ps -ef` will give you the `pid`. Is there any other need for your problem statement?

Comment: @Bill Good question. As you can see, the four processes have the same name `bash`. I don't know which is the one I want to kill, e.g. `run.sh parameter3`.

Comment: @JackWM Take a look at the additions to my answer.

Comment: @JackWM you can distinguish them using `parameter3`. run `ps -ef | grep parameter3` and this will give you the pid of a process which contains `parameter3`. You can adapt this to your need. I tend to keep things as simple as possible. If all you need is to identify a `pid` for killing it, I really do not see any need for `bg` and `fg`, making life complicated :)

Comment: @Bill that is awesome!

Comment: @JackWM I will post this as a answer :)